# How to move user in-app purchase information to other app?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

My apps are currently in the App Store.

Later I will remove this app from the AppStore and submit a new app.

So, the old app in-app purcharse user information must be moved to the new app.

What is the best way? Is there a safe way?

How to write the best code? Is there sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official, supported way of doing this. That is, your new app will never be able to "restore purchases" as you can with the old one.

I suppose you could have a button (or URL scheme) in your old app that sent data to the new one (using a URL scheme). Of course that could be faked unless you're careful.

You also want to be careful about what data you transfer. Apple may reject if you're circumventing an IAP in the new app, for example.

Comment: In any way, if their information has been obtained. i give to free coupons or promo code to in-app purchase. this possible?

Comment: There are no promo codes for IAP. You could ask Apple if they'd allow "upgrade coupons." They've offered one-off exceptions in the past. I just don't think you can rely on getting one.